# Google Calendar Orderby when using two linq queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts to display a stacked column chart. I am using entity framework and linq queries to gather my data from the db.

The problems I am having is:

1. that it will not order the chart. I have ordered the chart but the x-axis remains un-ordered. Can this be done through the linq query or could I do it in the script?
2. Currently it only displays x-axis values for data that I have. Example is on the x-axis I have month number but it only displays marks for data I have eg. 1,4,5,6. Is there a way to include from 1-12 although there is no data for that particular month number?

Code:

```
   #region Total Hours Per Month sick

        var querythpshols = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                             where (r.StartDate) >= dateAndTime
                             group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g                              
                             select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(h => h.HoursTaken)});


        var resultthpshols = querythpshols.ToList();



        var datachartthpshols = new object[resultthpshols.Count];
        int G = 0;
        foreach (var i in resultthpshols)
        {
            datachartthpshols[G] = new object[] { i.Value.ToString(), i.Count };
            G++;
        }
        string datathpshols = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datachartthpshols, Formatting.None);
        ViewBag.datajthpshols = new HtmlString(datathpshols);

        #endregion

        #region Total Hours Per Month
        var querythpshols1 = (from r in db.HolidayRequestForms
                              where (r.StartDate) <= dateAndTime
                              group r by r.MonthOfHoliday into g                 
                              select new { Value = g.Key, Count1 = g.Sum(r => r.HoursTaken) })
                               ;

        var resultthpshols1 = querythpshols1.ToList();

        var datachartthpshols1 = new object[resultthpshols1.Count];
        int P = 0;
        foreach (var i in resultthpshols1)
        {
            datachartthpshols1[P] = new object[] { i.Value.ToString(), i.Count1 };
            P++;
        }
        string datathpshols1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datachartthpshols1, Formatting.None);
        ViewBag.datajthpshols1 = new HtmlString(datathpshols1);

        #endregion
```

Script:

```
    @*TOTAL HOURS PER MONTH CHART*@
<scipt>
    <script>
        var datathpshols = '@ViewBag.datajthpshols';
        var datassthpshols = JSON.parse(datathpshols);

        var datathpshols1 = '@ViewBag.datajthpshols1';
        var datassthpshols1 = JSON.parse(datathpshols1);

    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartA);

        // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
        // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
        // draws it.
        function drawChartA() {

            // Create the data table.

            var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data1.addColumn('string', 'Value');
            data1.addColumn('number', 'Holiday Hours Booked');
            data1.addRows(datassthpshols);

            var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data2.addColumn('string', 'Value');
            data2.addColumn('number', 'Holiday Hours Taken');
            data2.addRows(datassthpshols1);

            var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);


            // Set chart options
            var options = {
                'title': 'Holiday Hours Taken Per Month',
                'width': 600,
                'height': 350,
                'hAxis': { title: 'Month Number' },
                'vAxis': { title: 'Holiday Hours Taken' },
                'is3D': true,
                'isStacked': true,
                'legend': 'right'
            };

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartTHPShols_div'));
            chart.draw(joinedData, options);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use data table method --> `sort` -- to order the x-axis.

```
joinedData.sort([{column: 0}]);
```

2) **strings** produce a *discrete* axis, and will only display the data available. **numbers** produce a *continuous* axis, and provide much more flexibility for the axis ticks. probably the most simplest solution would be to use a data view to convert the x-axis to numbers. (use the data view to draw the chart)

```
var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(joinedData);
dataView.setColumns([{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return parseFloat(dt.getValue(row, 0));
  },
  label: joinedData.getColumnLabel(0),
  type: 'number'
}, 1, 2]);
chart.draw(dataView, options);
```

Comment: Where do I add the sort? I tried adding it `chart.draw(joinedData.sort([{column: 0}]), options);`

Comment: I figured it all out thanks!! I had it converted to string in my controller so I changed that and simply added ticks. Thanks for the help